# How can i avoid the don't repeat your self rule with this function

Tags: javascript, coding-efficiency

He Developers,

I want to know your opinion about how to wright this code better.

If you click on button star3 it will turend as a yellow star stars underneath are also yellow. The star above star3 is just grey.

Thats what i got and what i need but i want to know how i can be more efficient in my code..

```js
var star = document.getElementById("star-0");
 var star1 = document.getElementById("star-1");
 var star2 = document.getElementById("star-2");
 var star3 = document.getElementById("star-3");
 var star4 = document.getElementById("star-4");
 var img = 'url(img/star.png)';
 var img2 = 'url(img/star2.png)';


star4.addEventListener('click', function(){
   star.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star1.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star2.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star3.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star4.style.backgroundImage = img2;
});

star3.addEventListener('click', function(){
   star.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star1.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star2.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star3.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star4.style.backgroundImage = img;
});

star2.addEventListener('click', function(){
   star.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star1.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star2.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star3.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star4.style.backgroundImage = img;
});

star1.addEventListener('click', function(){
   star.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star1.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star2.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star3.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star4.style.backgroundImage = img;
});

star.addEventListener('click', function(){
   star.style.backgroundImage = img2;
   star1.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star2.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star3.style.backgroundImage = img;
   star4.style.backgroundImage = img;
});
```

Comment: Create a new function that contains everything that is shared. Use parameters for everything that is variable.

Comment: Your snippet is not working

Comment: @osmanraifgunes JS to be working. The HTML he's trying to attach the click to just isn't here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about improving *working* code.

Comment: @FelixKling You're allowed to ask for help improving your code. It isn't broken but it's not doing what he wants in the way he wants. We can still help him

Comment: @Pabs123: It's borderline. Might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I suppose. Just seems like it's easier to give him a small hint and point in the right direction than just close the question

Comment: Maybe "Too broad" would have been a better close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to implement rating stars. If you insist on only using JS not using any smarts or meta-data in HTML. Here is the function I would simplify it to:

```js
var star = document.getElementById("star-0");
 var star1 = document.getElementById("star-1");
 var star2 = document.getElementById("star-2");
 var star3 = document.getElementById("star-3");
 var star4 = document.getElementById("star-4");
 var img = 'url(img/star.png)';
 var img2 = 'url(img/star2.png)';

function updateRating(rating) {
  var stars = [star, star1, star2, star3, star4];
  for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    var appliedImage = img;
    if ((i + 1) < rating) {
      appliedImage = img2;
    }
    
    stars[i].style.backgroundImage = appliedImage;
  }
}


star4.addEventListener('click', function(){
   updateRating(5);
});

star3.addEventListener('click', function(){
   updateRating(4);
});

star2.addEventListener('click', function(){
   updateRating(3);
});

star1.addEventListener('click', function(){
   updateRating(2);
});

star.addEventListener('click', function(){
   updateRating(1);
});
```

Comment: Nice! i will figure it out to trying this way of coding. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give all of the stars a common class like `class="stars"`. Then do:

`var star1 = document.querySelector('.stars');`

From there you can attach an event listener to them instead of writing each one out individually.

Inside of the click listener, make the background of the current event target's and all the ones with an id lower than itself be `img2`.

Answer (score 0):

Use one function to add all the stars and call it with the click event.  Pass in the id of the star.  Check with if statements and stop when it matches.